# Enable CORS with Hazelcast

Tags: angularjs, rest, hazelcast

I am currently using Hazelcast to expose a RestAPI for an Angular Client.

Is there any way to allow CORS on our Hazelcast server ?

I can't find anything about that in their documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hazelcast is not designed to be exposed to the Internet, that said the REST API is not designed to be used by web applications directly. If you use node.js you might consider using the node.js client.

To answer the question itself: CORS is not supported for the reason stated above.